# Android BuildConfig Field generating String incorrectly

Tags: android, gradle

The last day starting a new project I was creating some variables in the build config as a good practice to handle them separately between release and debug builds like this:

```
...
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        buildConfigField("String", "PARSE_APP_ID", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
        buildConfigField("String", "PARSE_CLIENT_ID", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
        buildConfigField("String", "FACEBOOK_APP_ID", "999999999999999")
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    debug{
        minifyEnabled false
        buildConfigField("String", "PARSE_APP_ID", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
        buildConfigField("String", "PARSE_CLIENT_ID", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
        buildConfigField("String", "FACEBOOK_APP_ID", "999999999999999")
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
...
```

The problem is that it was not creating the Strings correctly it was printing the strings directly without the quotation marks like this:

```
public final class BuildConfig {
  .....
  // Fields from build type: debug
  public static final String FACEBOOK_APP_ID = 99999999999999999;
  public static final String PARSE_APP_ID = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;
  public static final String PARSE_CLIENT_ID = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;
}
```

Obviously this will give you compile errors, I tried to find here in stackoverflow how to fix this since this was causing erros in my build, haven't found anything about this. How to make gradle  print the Strings correctly with the quotation marks?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

After writing this I have found the way, it seems that the values are printed in the same way they are defined so if you add escaped quotation marks to this it will work, example:

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            buildConfigField("String", "PARSE_APP_ID", '"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"')
            buildConfigField("String", "PARSE_CLIENT_ID", '"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"')
            buildConfigField("String", "FACEBOOK_APP_ID", '"999999999999999"')
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
```

After that, Rebuild and it will print the Strings values correctly:

```
public final class BuildConfig {
  ....
  // Fields from build type: debug
  public static final String FACEBOOK_APP_ID = "999999999999999999";
  public static final String PARSE_APP_ID = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
  public static final String PARSE_CLIENT_ID = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
}
```

Comment: Or, use single quotes in the Groovy code (`'"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"'`).

Comment: How to prevent BuildConfig  from apk decode.because after using above code if decode apk all details in single place.It is not secure. Any other way prevent this BuildConfigFields from reverse engineering

Comment: this is workaround for a bug right? this can't be the intended behavior.

Comment: @Nick i think so but maybe you can do some metaprogramming where the string represent actual code that you want to add. Grovy enables those things maybe you wish to add many variables inside a loop and change the name dynamically or something.

Answer (score 5):

**in app build.gradle**

```
def buildTimeAndVersion = releaseTime() + "-" + getSvnVersion()    
buildTypes {
    debug {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        buildConfigField "String", 'BIULD_TIME', "\"${buildTimeAndVersion}\""
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
....
}

static def releaseTime() {
return new Date().format("yyyyMMdd", TimeZone.getDefault())
}

def getSvnVersion() {
def pro = ("svnversion -c " + getBuildDir().parent).execute()
pro.waitFor()
def version = pro.in.text
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d+\\:)?(\\d+)\\D?")
Matcher m = p.matcher(version)
if (m.find()) {
    version = m.group(m.groupCount())
}
try {
    return version
} catch (e) {
    println e.getMessage()
}
return 0
}
```

**then in BuildConfig file**

```
public final class BuildConfig {
public static final boolean DEBUG = Boolean.parseBoolean("true"); 
public static final String APPLICATION_ID = "xxx.xxxxxxxx.xxx"; 
public static final String BUILD_TYPE = "debug";  
public static final String FLAVOR = "";  
public static final int VERSION_CODE = 53;  
public static final String VERSION_NAME = "5.4.4";  
// Fields from build type: debug  
public static final String BIULD_TIME = "20181030-2595";  
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, yitai wei! Code-only answers are discouraged here, as they provide no insight into how the problem was solved. Please update your solution to include an explanation of how your code solces the OP's problem :)