# Android Studio gradle buildConfigField setup

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I was looking through and open source application [here](https://github.com/nickbutcher/plaid) and saw this line of code in [this](https://github.com/nickbutcher/plaid/blob/master/app/build.gradle) file:

`buildConfigField "String", "DRIBBBLE_CLIENT_ID", "\"${dribbble_client_id}\""`

How does something like this work, mainly where or what is ${dribble_client_id} stored or defined?

Thanks

Comment: Answered in this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30796533/how-to-generate-buildconfigfield-with-string-type)

Comment: @user7790438: That question and answers cover the syntax of `buildConfigField`, not where `dribble_client_id` comes from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That could be defined in any of the `gradle.properties` files:

- In the module root
- In the project root
- In the Gradle home (e.g., `~/.gradle` on Linux and macOS)

There's also a syntax for using environment variables to inject values like that, but that approach didn't use to work with Android Studio, and I am not aware that it now does. It would work for command-line builds (e.g., CI servers).

I think that there is a command-line switch approach as well for defining properties like these.

Personally, I use `gradle.properties`.

Comment: Looking at gradle.properties file that seems to be the case in the app I mentioned. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can see：http://qiita.com/shts/items/d94834437b22712415c5

```
buildConfigField "String", "PARSE_API_ID", "\"${project.property("parseApiId")}\""
```