# ERROR: Gradle sync failed: Could not get unknown property 'API_KEY' for DefaultConfig_Decorated

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

> ERROR: Could not get unknown property 'API_KEY' for DefaultConfig_Decorated{name=main, dimension=null, minSdkVersion=null, targetSdkVersion=null, renderscriptTargetApi=null, renderscriptSupportModeEnabled=null, renderscriptSupportModeBlasEnabled=null, renderscriptNdkModeEnabled=null, versionCode=null, versionName=null, applicationId=null, testApplicationId=null, testInstrumentationRunner=null, testInstrumentationRunnerArguments={}, testHandleProfiling=null, testFunctionalTest=null, signingConfig=null, resConfig=null, mBuildConfigFields={}, mResValues={}, mProguardFiles=[], mConsumerProguardFiles=[], mManifestPlaceholders={}, mWearAppUnbundled=null} of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.DefaultConfig.
>       apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        buildConfigField("String", "API_KEY", API_KEY)        //error here
        buildConfigField("String", "ER_API_KEY", ER_API_KEY)
        applicationId "com.gpads.gautham.imagetotextanalysis"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 2
        versionName "2.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    // ... other values
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate buildConfigField with String type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30796533/how-to-generate-buildconfigfield-with-string-type)

Comment: package com.gpads.gautham.imagetotextanalysis;

public final class BuildConfig {
  public static final boolean DEBUG = Boolean.parseBoolean("true");
  public static final String APPLICATION_ID = "com.gpads.gautham.imagetotextanalysis";
  public static final String BUILD_TYPE = "debug";
  public static final String FLAVOR = "";
  public static final int VERSION_CODE = 2;
  public static final String VERSION_NAME = "2.0";
}
 @HemantParmar this is my BuildConfig.java

Answer (score 6):

Change this    buildConfigField("String", "API_KEY", API_KEY)
Into this

```
    buildConfigField "String", "API_KEY", "\" API_KEY\""
```

Answer (score 2):

To avoid any errors with your code add this snippet, found this as a solution for my movie project:

```
def getProperty(String filename, String propName) {
    def propsFile = rootProject.file(filename)
    if (propsFile.exists()) {
        def props = new Properties()
        props.load(new FileInputStream(propsFile))
        if (props[propName] != null) {
            return props[propName]
        } else {
            print("No such property " + propName + " in file " + filename);
        }
    } else {
        print(filename + " does not exist!")
    }
}
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        buildConfigField "String", "API_KEY", "\"${getProperty("local.properties", API_KEY)}\""
        buildConfigField "String", "\"${getProperty("local.properties", ER_API_KEY)}\""
        applicationId "com.gpads.gautham.imagetotextanalysis"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 2
        versionName "2.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the only solution which worked for me thanks

Answer (score 1):

The error is that **you are trying to use something you did not define.**

As a solution, you have several ways to initialize the configuration field:

---

. In the same scope it could be:

Look at the following code where `API_KEY_2` is defined.

```
android {
    //...
    defaultConfig {
        //...
        def API_KEY_2 = "API_KEY_2"
        buildConfigField("String", "API_KEY", API_KEY_2)
    }
}
```

---

. Or in a global scope:

### build.gradle

```
class Globals {
    static String API_KEY_2 = "API_KEY_2"
}

android {
    //...
    defaultConfig {
        //...
        def API_KEY_2 = "API_KEY_2"
        buildConfigField("String", "API_KEY", API_KEY_2)
    }
}
```

*Note:* I don't recommend using `BuildConfig.SOMETHING` to initialize a buildConfigField

GL

Answer (score 0):

If you get an `"illegal start of expression"` using [Braian Coronel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62799357), you can try to escape the quotes with:

```
def API_KEY_2 = "your api key"
buildConfigField("String", "API_KEY", "\"API_KEY_2 \"")
```

Comment: Can you clarify in which solution was not working, in which potential particular setup you tested it, and what your alternative is changing? Code only answers are considered low-quality

Comment: If I didn't add like "\"API_KEY_2 \"", getting error as illegal start of expression

Comment: can you link which solution you were referring to? there are 3 other answers

Comment: For @Braian Coronel reply

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I now consider it a contribution to meaningfully extend a cleanly referenced existing answer.