# Is there a way to use .env variables in Android (java) like we do in laravel?

Tags: java, android

I don't know if this is off-topic, but in Laravel, we can set variables in a `.env` file, which we can then access using a `getenv()` function to prevent from hard coding it in, which can be not secure.

Can we do the same in Android Studio (using Java)? As there is some information I rather not hard code.

Hope this makes sense.

I tried setting the variables in a class and accessing them through the class, but I feel there is a better way that is more similar to how it is done in Laravel.

Here's what I'm doing now but it's not what I'm looking for:

```java
public class EnvVariables {
    public final String API_KEY = "some API key";
    public final String API_ENDPOINT = "https://example.com/api/v1/endpoint";
}
```

Then I used these variables wherever I needed them.

This does the job, BUT the class is still easily accessible, whereas a `.env` is not (as it shouldn't be).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The closest (In my opinion) we have to environmental variables, would be `buildConfig` fields, which you make in build.gradle, like this :

`buildConfigField "String", "variable_name", "variable_value"`

you would do something like this:

```
 flavorDimensions "default"   
 productFlavors {
    dev {
buildConfigField "String", "SERVER_TEST", "\"http://192.618..\""
buildConfigField "String", "SERVER_MAIN", "\"https://68.5...\""
buildConfigField "String", "API_KEY", "dev API key"
    }
     prod {
buildConfigField "String", "SERVER_TEST", "\"http://192.618..\""
buildConfigField "String", "SERVER_MAIN", "\"https://68.5...\""
buildConfigField "String", "API_KEY", "prod API key"
    }
```

which you can then access like this :

```
BuildConfig.API_KEY
```

have a look at these for more info :

[How to generate buildConfigField with String type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30796533/how-to-generate-buildconfigfield-with-string-type)

and this for creating different flavors :

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants

---

As a side note, `buildConfig` fields are used for values specifically related to a particular build or a group of builds, for your situation of wanting to store API keys it's a good example, but should not be used to just store all constant values for an app.

If you have different versions of an app (free, premium, etc) which uses different API keys, build config is the better way of doing it, as you can see from my code above, depending on the build variant you launch, the api key will change.

Comment: Ahhh that makes more sense, it is similar to how a `.env` file is used. Thanks :)

Comment: Hey... quick question. By `build.gradle`, do you mean `build.gradle (app)` or `build.gradle (MyProject)`?

Comment: no worries, different flavors(versions) of apps, as well as build config fields are defined in `build.gradle(app)` and not the root level gradle. @UndercoverCoder

Comment: Thanks for the quick response :)

Comment: no worries :D that link I posted for flavours should explain how to make different versions of an app, that should get you started @UndercoverCoder

Answer (score 2):

Put these values in String file

```
res>values>string.xml
```

Like this

```
<string name="api_endpoint">https://example.com/api/v1/endpoint</string>
```

And access it via

```
 getResources().getString(R.string.api_endpoint)
```

In your Fragment/Activity

Comment: In some context, your answer is also correct, because the example shown in question leads to that thought

Comment: @a_local_nobody - They're both very good answers :) never seen your way of doing it so I learned something from it :D

Comment: Hey @UndercoverCoder 
Does this answer provide proper security ?? I am a noob so don’t know much Plz tell

Comment: @Abhishekkumar you probably know by now, but no, none of the answers provide any security, as both are readable in clear text inside the apk

Comment: @Tobias Yes, you are right. But I don't know what can be done for providing better security?