# How to use BuildConfig.API_KEY in Android App

Tags: android

I am following a lesson on Android App development but still unable as to how to use the TMDB_API_KEY  and used in: `api.getTopRatedMovies(BuildConfig.TMDB_API_KEY, LANGUAGE, page).enqueue(call);`. I tried creating class level variable `public static final String TMDB_API_KEY = "xxxxxxxxxxx";` in `public class MoviesRepository` but it did not work. I also tried adding it in gradle.properties but no success. 
I added following inside **buildTypes** in **build.gradle(App)** file: `debug { buildConfigField 'String', "TMDB_API_KEY", "xxxxxxxxxx" }` But now I am getting another error:

> error: cannot find symbol private static MoviesRepository repository;
>   ^ symbol: variable xxxxxxxxxxxxx

Note xxx is api key. What I am doing wrong?

**EDIT:** I was not escaping quotes, now following solved the issue:

```
debug { buildConfigField 'String', "TMDB_API_KEY", "\"xxxxxxxxxxxxxx\"" }
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-tips#share-custom-fields-and-resource-values-with-your-app-code

Comment: check this link https://stackoverflow.com/q/30796533/3497972

Comment: Thanks all, I was not escaping quotes, now following solved the issue: debug {
            buildConfigField 'String', "TMDB_API_KEY", "\"xxxxxxxxxxxxxx\""
        }