# How to Inject host and schema in AndroidManifest.xml for Android Deeplinking

Tags: android, android-manifest, deep-linking

I am trying to dynamically inject the url schema and path into my AndroidManifest.xml file using build.gradle as [referenecd here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-build-variables)

However, this does not allow deeplinks to trigger.

I tested my deeplinking works when I use static values in the AndroidManifest.xml.

```
            // AndroidManifest.xml
            <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:scheme="${appScheme}"
                android:host="${hostName}"
                android:path="/path2" />

            <data
                android:scheme="${appScheme}"
                android:host="${hostName}"
                android:path="/path1" />
        </intent-filter>




// build.gradle (:app)
defaulConfig {
        manifestPlaceholders = [
        hostName: "www.host_name.com",
        appScheme: "https"
    ]
}


  demo {
        resValue "string", "hostName", "www.host_demo.com"
        resValue "string", "appScheme", "https"
    }

    staging {
        resValue "string", "hostName", "www.host_staging.com"
        resValue "string", "appScheme", "http"
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by `However, this does not allow deeplinks to trigger.`? is it not working with resValue defined on each flavor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think what you can do here is define those strings in your defaultConfig, like this:

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        flavorDimensions 'yourAppName'

        resValue "string", "host_name", "www.live_demo.com"
        resValue "string", "app_scheme", "http"

        productFlavors {
            demo {
                dimension 'yourAppName'
                resValue "string", "host_name", "www.host_demo.com"
            }

            staging {
                dimension 'yourAppName'
                resValue "string", "host_name", "www.host_staging.com"
            }
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

after rebuilding, `host_name` and `app_scheme` will be generated for you if you prefer to have productFlavours like what you have defined on you code. This works for me on every project i handled :)

```
app/build/generated/res/resValues/debug/values/gradleResValues.xml
app/build/generated/res/resValues/demo/values/gradleResValues.xml
app/build/generated/res/resValues/staging/values/gradleResValues.xml
```

Then from your `AndroidManifest.xml` file, you can call `@string/host_name` instead of `${hostName}`.

```
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data
            android:scheme="@string/app_scheme"
            android:host="@string/host_name"
            android:path="/path2" />

        <data
            android:scheme="@string/app_scheme"
            android:host="@string/host_name"
            android:path="/path1" />
    </intent-filter>
```

PS: I prefer defining string resources with snake case. :)

Comment: Moving the resValue to defaultConfig worked. Thanks!

PS: I defined the strings as camelCase because that is how the docs do it.

Comment: Ah i see, Nice! :)